# I need to disable pointer (cursor) and then enable it after a set time

Tags: javascript

I want to disable my mouse cursor (so all elements are not-clickable) for 6 seconds and then enable it again.

Comment: css: `html.locked { pointer-events: none; }`. then toggle the `locked` class on the root

Comment: Do you want it to be invisible or just non-functional? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I wanted it non-functional. Kamil Kiełczewski's code did the job beautifully. :-)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can put invisible `<div>` in front (with full window size)

```js
function test() {
  console.log('button clicked')
}

function dis() {
  curtine.classList.toggle('show')
  setTimeout(x=>curtine.classList.toggle('show'),6000);
}
```

```css
#curtine { 
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position: fixed; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15); /* change 15 to 0*/
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh;
  display: none;
}

#curtine.show { display: block; cursor: none }
```

```html
<button onclick="test()">Some button</button>

<button onclick="dis()">disable cursor</button>

<div id=curtine></div>
```